# Original Host Request through HAProxy

Tags: oauth, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy to load balance an API which uses OAuth. As part of OAuth there is a hash that uses the requested URL in part of it. In the API code, the url when sent to the server from the LB contains the port. This makes the hash not match because the sent hash does not contain the port, however, the server side hash does.

Is there a way to send the requested host in the x-forwarded-host header via an option like x-forward-for? Or do I need to alter the header via reqadd in the backend. And if so, is there a way to get the host without having to hard code it?